# Como validar maior valor recebido no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, moodle

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna os últimos acessos dos usuários no sistema. Gostaria de saber como eu poderia tratar pra me retornar apenas as data que fossem maiores que 15 dias.

A consulta é essa:

```sql
SELECT u.id, concat(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) as nome,from_unixtime(MAX(l.time)),
DATEDIFF(now(),from_unixtime(MAX(l.time))) as Dias
FROM mdl_role_assignments rs
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id=rs.userid
    INNER JOIN mdl_context e ON rs.contextid=e.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_log l ON l.userid=u.id
WHERE e.contextlevel=50 AND rs.roleid=5 AND e.instanceid=2174 AND l.course=e.instanceid
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstname,u.lastname
order by Dias desc
```

---

A tabela principal para essa operação é a **mdl_log** que guarda esses registros junto do iduser e o course (que usei para filtrar o curso de id=2174 em *e.instanceid*)

Já tentei passar a função MAX() no where, tentei passar esse mesmo SELECT dentro WHERE comparando o retorno com uma data qualquer... sem sucesso.

Comment: se você quer só os últimos 15 dias, não bastaria apenas comparar a data usando `(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY)`?

Comment: O problema é que a tabela guarda todas as datas dos acessos, por isso que passei o campo l.time dentro de max()

Comment: Lembrando que se eu tenho que pegar o _último acesso_ e que ele tenha sido a mais de 15 dias

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer a comparação no WHERE conforme indicado pelo @Ricardo Pontual

```
SELECT u.id, concat(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname) as nome, from_unixtime(MAX(l.time)),
DATEDIFF(now(),from_unixtime(MAX(l.time))) as Dias
FROM mdl_role_assignments rs
    INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id=rs.userid
    INNER JOIN mdl_context e ON rs.contextid=e.id
    INNER JOIN mdl_log l ON l.userid=u.id
WHERE e.contextlevel=50 AND rs.roleid=5 AND e.instanceid=2174 AND l.course=e.instanceid AND from_unixtime(l.time) > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY)
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstname,u.lastname
order by Dias desc
```

Dessa forma serão filtrados todos os registros dos últimos 15 dias e depois, se houver, será apresentada a última dessas datas. Se for para retornar TODAS as datas maiores que 15 dias (mais de um registro) remover o GROUP BY e o MAX.